# Programmatic call to Read NLP_CONFIGs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, nlp, facebook-messenger

I manage a few bots on Facebook and I normally use this curl call to set the NLP config for a page. I'd like to be able to *read* the nlp config as well. I can't find a documented approach nor was I able to 'guess' one. Anyone know?
thanks

> curl -i -X POST   -d "access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/nlp_configs?nlp_enabled=true&verbose=true&n_best=1&custom_token=WIT_SERVER_TOKEN"

Comment: Since https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/nlp_configs/#Reading currently contains nothing under the “Reading” heading, that might not currently be possible. I assume you tried a simple GET request already, did that get you any errors?

Comment: Yep - I tried GET.